# numpy: modifyng a transposed array don't work as expected

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

I have, from a more complex program, this code:

```
import numpy as np

ph=np.arange(6).reshape([2,3])
T=np.transpose(ph)
print 'T:\n',T
print 'ph:\n',ph              # printing arrays before for cycle
for i in range(0,len(T)):
  T[i]=2*T[i]
print 'ph:\n', ph             # printing arrays after for cycle
print 'T:\n',T
```

i expect to have in output T and

```
ph:
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
```

instead, i have

```
ph:
[[ 0  2  4]
 [ 6  8 10]]
T:
[[ 0  6]
 [ 2  8]
 [ 4 10]]
```

So when i multiply *2 every line of T inside the for cicle, I am doing the same to ph. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the reason in the [docstring of `np.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
 Returns
 ------- p : ndarray
     `a` with its axes permuted.  A view is returned whenever
     possible.
```

Solution is to use `T = ph.T.copy()` if you don't want the view, but a copy.

Comment: [This section](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-1529ae93dd5d431ffe3a1001a4ab1a394e70a5f2) of the numpy tutorial goes over the difference between views and copies.

Answer (score 1):

`transpose` returns a view to the original array.  To solve your problem, make a copy, like:

```
T=np.transpose(ph).copy()
```